# How to render a html page, which exists in one of the subfolders and has its own stylesheets and its own script, using express and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to render a HTML page, which exists in one of the sub folders and has its own style-sheets and its own script, using express and node, I have downloaded separate login page, etc, which I want to render in this manner.

Comment: Do you have any example code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following file system:

```
server.js (file)
website (directory)
  -> index.html
     style.css
     code.js
```

To serve your entire `website` directory (the `index.html` file, the `style.css` file and other files), you will need to use the express built-in middleware function `express.static`.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(website)) // your directory you want to expose

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on *3000!')) // 3000 is just an example port
```